Spring - keep getting Redis serialisation error
I keep getting this error, with the request repository, that I'm trying to store in Redis.
The error I keep getting:
Error
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Redis serialiser
@Bean
// setting a custom OAuth2AuthorizationRequest serializer for Redis
fun oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedisSerializer(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): RedisSerializer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {
    return object : RedisSerializer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {
        private val serializer = GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)
        override fun serialize(value: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?): ByteArray? {
            return try {
                if (value == null) {
                    null
                } else {
                    println("Serializing: $value")
                    serializer.serialize(value)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw SerializationException("Error serializing OAuth2AuthorizationRequest", e)
            }
        }

        override fun deserialize(bytes: ByteArray?): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
            return try {
                if (bytes == null || bytes.isEmpty()) {
                    println("Deserialization: Received null or empty byte array")
                    null
                } else {
                    println("Deserializing bytes: ${bytes.joinToString(", ") { String.format("%02X", it) }}")
                    val result = serializer.deserialize(bytes)
                    println("Deserialized OAuth2AuthorizationRequest: $result")
                    result as? OAuth2AuthorizationRequest
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw SerializationException("Error deserializing OAuth2AuthorizationRequest", e)
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()

    // register modules for security if needed
    mapper.registerModule(CoreJackson2Module())
    mapper.registerModules(SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(loader))

    return mapper
}

Repository implementation
@Repository
internal class RedisAuthorizationRequestRepository(
    private val redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>,
    springSessionProperties: SpringSessionProperties,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) : ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    private val redisKeyPrefix = springSessionProperties.redis?.oauth2RequestNamespace

    override fun saveAuthorizationRequest(
        authorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange
    ): Mono<Void> {
        return constructRedisKey(exchange).flatMap { redisKey ->
            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                val hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>()
                val fieldsMap = objectMapper.convertValue(
                    authorizationRequest,
                    object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {}
                )
                hashOperations.putAll(redisKey, fieldsMap).then()
            } else {
                redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().delete(redisKey).then()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        return constructRedisKey(exchange).flatMap { redisKey ->
            redisTemplate.opsForHash<String, Any>().entries(redisKey)
                .collectMap({ it.key as String }, { it.value })
                .mapNotNull { map ->
                    if (map.isEmpty()) {
                        null
                    } else {
                        objectMapper.convertValue(map, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest::class.java)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}

Redis Template
  @Bean
    // OAuth2AuthorizationRequest
    // reactive Redis Template for OAuth2AuthorizationRequest objects
    fun reactiveOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedisTemplate(
        connectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
        oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedisSerializer: RedisSerializer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>
    ): ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {
        val serializationContext = RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext<String, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>()
            .key(StringRedisSerializer())
            .value(oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedisSerializer)
            .hashKey(StringRedisSerializer())
            .hashValue(oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedisSerializer)
            .build()
        return ReactiveRedisTemplate(connectionFactory, serializationContext)
    }

It keeps saying string cannot be cast to OAuth2AuthorizationRequest... but I just cannot resolve the error. What can I try next?

closing issue. Using generic serialiser of type Any? to handle different input types to be serialised, e.g. String, LinkedHashMap, Array etc.
